# UITableView and PanGesture in three directions

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a table view with some items that should be dragged to another view. I need to add pan gesture recognizer that only can drag the items to right, top right and top left directions. 
I have no idea how can I do this. What angle should be between the two points?

In other words I need to block table view scrolling when user drag item and he moving it. 
I try to implement

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
```

method but in this method I cant receive "changed" state from pan gesture to calculate angle.

Comment: I would do it in your pan handler – can you post that? The selector that you connect the pan gesture to when you create it is the one I'm talking about.

Comment: Also, I'm a bit confused what table views have to do with this. Can you elaborate? Maybe post a gif or picture of intended functionality?